# Get Byte from memory address?

Tags: c++, memory, byte, memory-address

I'm still learning c++ and have spent hours trying to figure out a way to get a byte stored at a certain memory address, in my case ALL (well, almost all) memory addresses aren't dynamic - so addresses pointing to, for example variables will not change.

So I'm trying to retrieve a single byte stored at a known memory address.
For example let's say: `0x20000`

the byte i'm trying to retrieve is, for example, let's say `0xEF`.

Now how would i retrieve the byte without using the dereference operator?
So basically i need to get `0xEF` without having to declare what type of data type it is, like literally just physically get the byte `0xEF`.
Hopefully this makes sense, I'm quite a noob :/

Comment: `uint8_t mybyte = *reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(0x20000);`

Comment: When you say `0xEF` is that the offset from memory location `0x20000`?

Comment: If Galik is correct, then add `0xef` to the expression I posted earlier.

Comment: @md5i your first message was what i was looking for :) If you would've posted it below i would've marked it as answer! Thanks for help though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now how would i retrieve the byte without using the dereference operator?

You cannot do this without dereferencing the accessed address. The smallest data type you can address is a `char`. For bytes there's usually a `typedef unsigned char uint8_t` used.

So you have to access the memory address using a `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(addr)` and dereference to get the value.

Answer (score 5):

Dereferencing the memory address is the only way to get the byte value.

Typecasting the memory address to a typed pointer and then dereferencing it is the most **direct** way, eg:

```
unsigned char value = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(0x20000));
```

However, to answer your question:

> how would i retrieve the byte *without using the dereference operator*?

You can dereference the memory **indirectly** by using [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) or similar function, eg:

```
#include <cstring>

unsigned char value;
std::memcpy(&value, (void*)0x20000, 1);
```